# InvocatoinTargetExceptoin when using JavaFx 11 Robot API

Tags: java, exception, javafx, javafx-11

JavaFx 11 comes with a Robot API and I was excited to use it. The problem is that just instantiating the Robot results in an InvocationTargetException.

Has anyone successfully used the JavaFx 11 Robot, and if so how?

Note: I added JavaFx 11 as a dependency in maven

Edit: Some code that will reproduce the error

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.robot.Robot;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Scene scene = new Scene(new AnchorPane(), 400, 400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
... 1 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.createRobot()Lcom/sun/glass/ui/GlassRobot;
at javafx.scene.robot.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:78)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: worksforme .... not using maven, though

Comment: Same here. Works fine using Gradle. Post your settings (Java/JavaFX versions, OS, and any VM options you may have set.

Comment: I updated to eclipse 2018-09 and that seemed to fix my problem. It seems eclipse oxygen doesn't play well with Java/Fx 11.